# Error while connecting to Tibco topic from .net - ClientId already exists

Tags: .net, tibco, ems

using a c# client am subscribing to a Tibco topic using a durable subscriber.  am using below code

```
TopicConnectionFactory factory = new TIBCO.EMS.TopicConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
TopicConnection connection = factory.CreateTopicConnection(userName, password);
connection.ClientID = clientID;
TopicSession session = connection.CreateTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.CreateTopic(topicName);
TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.CreateDurableSubscriber(topic, durableName); 
connection.Start();
```

When the program runs for the first time, the above code is working fine and am able to receive the messages.  but when i stop my client program and try to run it again, then from now onwards, am not able to connect to topic at all.  it is giving me a error

```
ClientId already exists at line
connection.ClientID = clientID;
```

am not sure what is the role of clientId.  do i need to give unique clientid each time i connect to TOPIC?

kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a unique clientId?

Comment: Not yet, am not sure what is the role of clientId? trying unique clientId each time might solve the problem, but what issue it will create?  what functionality of ClientId will i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this.  instead of Receive method, i used a method ReceiveNoWait method, then all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, every connection should have a unique clientId. Otherwise you'll get "ClientId already exists" if there is already a connection having the same clientId.